# How to update an m2m field programmatically in django signals

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-signals

I'm trying to automatically update an m2m field within my model class. It's an observe-execute if true type, meaning if my model instance has a certain attribute, assign it to this group or that group.
The model class looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_worker = models.BooleanField(_('Worker'), default=False, help_text='register as a worker')
    is_client = models.BooleanField(_('Client'), default=False, help_text='register as a client')
```

The signal looks like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def assign_user_to_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_client:
        instance.groups.add([g.pk for g in Group.objects.filter(name='clients')][0])
    elif instance.is_worker:
        instance.groups.add([g.pk for g in Group.objects.filter(name='workers')][0])
```

Usually, I may need to call the save() method on my instance, but the docs states otherwise, plus defying that just gets me a
`RecursionError`.
Could you please suggest a cleaner approach that best solves this? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I ended up extending the model's `save()` method like this:

```
from django.db import transaction


def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(User, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    transaction.on_commit(self.update_user_group)
    return instance

def update_user_group(self):
    if self.is_worker:
        self.groups.set([g.pk for g in Group.objects.filter(name='workers')])
    elif self.is_client:
        self.groups.set([g.pk for g in Group.objects.filter(name='clients')])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong with your current approach? Using `.add()` on a many-to-many relation should be sufficient to update the relation without then calling `.save()`

You're also doing an unnecessary list-comprehension. It is sufficient to do `Group.objects.filter(name='workers')[0]` or `Group.objects.filter(name='workers').first()`

Comment: Thank you @PetrMitsel. I tried this with the ```post_save ``` signal, however, it did not add the group-related object to the user instance as I thought. I eventually had to override my model's ```save()``` as stated in the edit.

Comment: Happy it works for you. I suppose a signal is not strictly necessary here, since you are trying to override the save behavior on one model and not create some other model instance or do something else that's unrelated.